# CKEditor XSS clean

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, xss

I've web-project, where I allow users to use CKEditor, and thats why I need to secure me from any XSS. How do I minimise any risks of being "attacked" with XSS?

I don't know if this will be enough, I guess no:

```
strip_tage(Input::get('text'), '<p><a><h1><h2>');
```

So question is how to be XSS Clean from CKEditor on server-side and what I need to do on CKEditor side, which plugins to remove (as I removed source code plugin, maybe I also should remove styles plugin??)???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

It was created specifically for sanitizing HTML and fixing invalid markup such as incorrectly nested tags or unescaped special characters.

It doesn't matter what plugins you remove from CKEditor, a malicious user can completely bypass CKEditor and submit any string they want.

`strip_tags` with `$allowable_tags` doesn't offer good enough protection from XSS, because scripts and styles can be embedded in tag attributes such as `href`, `onmouseover`, `onerror`, etc. It's also possible to reuse some of the application styles and scripts by adding `id` and `class` attributes.